# Points reduced without notification

Tags: support

It has occurred to me that I have several points reductions. There have been at least 2 (I don't remember my points exactly) each time by -2. For them there have been no notifications or relevant record in the reputation tab of user profile.

Probably there must be some votedown, but I have been wondering if this is normal to not get any notification for that.

Comment: See your [reputation tab](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17649/wtower?tab=reputation). Is it there?

Comment: That might be your Suggested Edits reputation. If user delete their post you lose the reputation. In this case you won't get any notifications for your lost reputation

Comment: @PatrickHofman, thanks, as I said the tab does not imediately show it but there is this little checkbox at the bottom which I missed, as the duplicate question's answer suggests.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan thx, missed that. Closing the question.